# Binding generic types together in a Map

Tags: java, generics

I have something like this as a field in a class

```
Map<Class<? extends Animal>, List<? extends Animal>> map;
```

How can I tell the compiler to guarentee that whenever I put something in this map I want the type of the Class and List to be the same each time (but of course I should be able to change the key type to any class that extends Animal when I need to), effectively binding the two together?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the code to add in a method:

```
public <T extends Animal> void add(Class<T> key, List<T> value) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom map like this:

```
class MyMap<T extends Animal> implements Map<Class<T>, List<T>>{
    // Choose any implementation of Map you want:
    Map<Class<T>, List<T>> map = new HashMap<Class<T>, List<T>>();

    // then delegate every method like this:
    @Override void clear(){
        map.clear();
    }

    // other methods
}
```

This will give you a `Map` which enforces the same type.